# To lower case in PHP or MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

Kind of strange question, I assume `PHP` is faster but maybe someone knows better.

Question is the following:

A table with approximately 10k rows, `varchar(550)` field. Field is indexed.

Select that retrieves data has a lot of `OR`-cases and does a `LIKE` scan for every condition.

Query is run from `PHP` script.

Would it be faster to lowercase search substring before running query in script?

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE LOWER('%substring_1%') OR field LIKE LOWER ('%substring_2%') OR ... field LIKE LOWER ('%substring_100%')
```

Or something similar to:

```
//$substr_array contains all substrings
$condition = "";
foreach ($substr_array as $substring) {
 $condition .= "field LIKE '%".mb_strtolower($substring, "UTF-8")."%' OR ";
}
$condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $condition";
$result = query($query);
```

Comment: What stops you from creating an experiment to test this yourself? You got the code, all you need is a reasonably filled table with (test)-data.

Comment: The SQL Server query optimiser will be smart enough to only calculate the lowercase values once, rather than for every row. I wouldn't bother optimising at that level—I'd try to figure out a way that you could avoid the LIKE '%whatever%' comparisons, because there's no way you can use an index with a query like that, so that'll be what's slowing things down. If you can't change your design to avoid that, I'd say the only way you'll get significantly better performance is to buy a bigger server.

Comment: Adimeus, I don't have clean evniroment and afraid that server loads or smth will interfere with tests. Also at this point it isn't smth that important to dedicate a lot of time to it.

Comment: Matt Gibson, I doubt that there is a way to change query structure - all substings are generated in PHP script and I have to use LIKEs for search. I cannot use FULLTEXT search due to encoding problems... Hmm. I just stumbled upon an idea of using UNION SELECT instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an opinion based question, but a question nonetheless. So here goes my answer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field LIKE LOWER('%substring_1%') 
OR field LIKE LOWER ('%substring_2%') 
OR ... field LIKE LOWER ('%substring_100%')
```

this scenario depends on how well you DB is structured. If you don't have a lot of records in your database then it should not matter giving the "outstanding" performances that we have nowadays...

**However:** *"Another way for case-insensitive matching is to use a different “collation”. The default collations used by SQL Server and MySQL do not distinguish between upper and lower case letters—they are case-insensitive by default."* (extract from **[use-the-index-luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions/case-insensitive-search)**)

You should read that article, it's very good.

Now down to the second part. The most expensive, as a performance cost, in the PHP code will be the `foreach()` statement. [HERE](http://www.phpbench.com/) you can find more info on how much time does a `foreach()` loop takes and a very good comparison with `for()` and `while()` loops. It's good to know them. So basically, what you do here is first take some time preparing the query, which costs time, and then actually running it, which costs time.

In conclusion, the real battle here will be: Which is faster? A `foreach()` or the `LOWER()` function in SQL.

Providing that I gave you some good materials to read in, and form your own conclusions, in my opinion, I think that the best way to go about this is to just leave the query and drop the `foreach()`, because queryes are the most cost-expensive and adding a `foreach()` will just slow you performance down. At least you cut something out of the picture. :)

I really hope that this helps you!
Keep on coding! 
Ares.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. You gave a really great idea regarding collation. And thanks for PHPBenchmark link - pretty interesting results. One thing though - according to tests foreach is faster than precalc + for.

Comment: I also runned some tests on dev enviroment and looks like simple WHERE OR is faster than other methods.

Comment: glad to be of help! As I said... the query is the way to go... `foreach()` or any loop + query will slow even more your performances...

Comment: Wow! Getting rid of those LOWER made query run twice faster!